# PostAsync removing the "+" character

Tags: c#

I need to send form data to a server but I am having a problem.

```
            HtmlDocument scraper = new HtmlDocument();

            string response = await client.GetStringAsync("hidden");
            scraper.LoadHtml(response);
            string gameToken = scraper.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div[1]/form/input[2]").Attributes["value"].Value.Replace("&quot;", @"""");
            string sessionToken = scraper.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div/div[1]/form/input[1]").Attributes["value"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(gameToken);

            string postData = $"fc-game[session_token]={sessionToken}&";
            postData += $"fc-game[data]={gameToken}";
            var content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var result = await client.PostAsync("https://httpbin.org/anything", content);
            string resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

the second request is where the problem is.
https://pastebin.com/AfnBZMTF

if you go to this pastbin link you will see a string and a response from `https://httpbin.org/anything`.
if you look at the data you will see that somehow the `+` character gets removed making the request fail.

Please help me!

Comment: Have you tried `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sessionToken)` yet?

Comment: there is no `+` shown in the question, so we can't really assess whether this removal is correct or incorrect. Can you show the actual URL / etc that we're meant to be looking at? But: `+` is a weird one, because it can mean "space"; you could try url-encoding it to `%2B` if you need the literal `+` (that's why the [tag:c++] tag is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B`)

Comment: yep that worked `%2B` thanks if you make an answer i will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, the response would be misunderstanding from `+` => `space`, you could test again with below

```
 Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("+")); //%2b
 Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(" ")); //+
```